# How to select radom items in a for loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to select random items inside a jQuery loop. I have a loop with 30 items where I'm adding some random numbers, now I don't want to add random numbers to all items at once, I would like to add random numbers to random items in the loop.

A good example would be, let's say I want my loop to add 5 to several random items of a loop as shown below

```
for( var i = 0; i < 30; i ++ ){
                 if( i 'is in range of radom'  ){
                    i + 5;
                 } else {
                    i + 0;
                 }
            }
```

It's like selecting a bunch of items inside a loop, next time selecting another bunch and so on. I can select like 10 random items in a loop to add 5 to, next loop another random 10 items are selected and so on and so forth.

Comment: Where is `radom` defined?

Comment: That was just an example

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean your 30 items is an array of 30 numbers.

Assuming you want to add a value (in your example, 5) to n random items (in your example, 10 items)

```js
const items = [/* 30 things here */];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   items[Math.random() * items.length] += 5;
}
```

This could possibly add 5 to the same item 10 times, if Math.random() returns similar values.

Comment: But I want all the 30 items to be there. only add 5 to 10 random items. the rest add 0

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

var random = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  random.push(getRandomInt(30));
}

var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  if (random.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
    results[i] = i + 5;
  } else {
    results[i] = i;
  }
}

console.log(random, results);
```

Assuming `random` is an array of "random" entries, you can populate a new array with 30 entries, in order, with salted results.

Results:

```
[
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  11,
  7,
  8,
  14,
  10,
  11,
  12,
  13,
  19,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  18,
  19,
  20,
  21,
  22,
  28,
  24,
  25,
  26,
  32,
  28,
  29
]
```

You can use `.indexOf()`:

> The **indexOf()** method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

If you have an Array of Numbers for example, you can check if a Number is in that array this way.